# Show that $a(-1) = (-1)a = -a $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a ring $R$ with identity 1, show that $$a(-1) = (-1)a = -a \qquad\forall\, a \in R$$ I have started with $a + (-a) = 0$ but cant proceed from here.

Comment: $(a)(-1)+(a)(1)=(a)(-1+1)=(a)(0)$. Prove that $(a)(0)=0$ using $(a)(0+0)=(a)(0)$.

Comment: Do you know Peano's Axioms?

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter The ring axioms are quite different from Peano's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use distribution for all it's worth, together with $1\cdot a = a \cdot 1 = a$:
$$
a + (-1) \cdot a \\= 1\cdot a + (-1)\cdot a \\= (1 + (-1)) \cdot a \\= 0\cdot a \\= 0$$
and thus, by the uniqueness of additive inverses (remember, if we forget multiplication, any ring becomes an abelian group), we get that $(-1) \cdot a = -a$. By the same reasoning, we get
$$
a + a\cdot (-1) = a(1 + (-1)) = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have $\space[1+(-1)]=0$.

Therefore $a\cdot [1+(-1)]=a\cdot 0=0$.

By left distributive law,
$$a\cdot 1+a\cdot (-1)=0$$
$$a+a\cdot (-1)=0.$$

Now $-a \in R$.  Adding $-a$ to both sides, we get
$$(-a)+[a+a\cdot (-1)]=(-a)+0,$$
or
$$[(-a)+a]+a\cdot (-1)=-a\quad [\text{associative property}]$$
or
$$0+a\cdot (-1)=-a,$$
or
$$a\cdot (-1)=-a.$$

Similarly we can do $[1+(-1)]\cdot a=0\cdot a=0$.

By right distributive law,
$$1 \cdot a+(-1)\cdot a=0$$
$$a+(-1)\cdot a=0.$$

Now $-a \in R$. Adding $-a$ to both sides and proceeding as before, we get $$(-1)\cdot a=-a.$$

Hence $a\cdot (-1)=(-1)\cdot a=-a$.